# Is a ratio of numerical derivatives, $\frac{dx}{dt} / \frac{dy}{dt}$, considered a "partial derivative"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, machine-learning, time-series

I am reading a paper on genetic programming by Lipson and Schmidt called "Distilling Free-Form Natural Laws from Experimental Data" at the following link: `https://science.sciencemag.org/content/324/5923/81/tab-figures-data`.

*- It's unrelated to the question, but the paper describes how to use
experimental data to derive the laws of physics through a machine
learning method called genetic programming.*

In this paper, **the authors claim "If our experiments collect time-series data, we can estimate the partial derivative between any pair of variables  by  taking  the  ratio  of  their  numerical  derivatives  over  time".** Here is a screenshot of the paragraph and respective "PDE".
[authors' statement on PDE derivation; includes PDE equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m056h.png)

Equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y} \approx \frac{dx}{dt} / \frac{dy}{dt}
\end{align}

This confuses me. I have taken multivariable calculus and a class on ODEs, and I use PDEs in physics, but **I have never heard someone define a partial derivative as a "ratio of two ordinary derivatives". Is this actually a partial derivative?**

Comment: As far as I can see in the picture there is absolutely no mention of PDEs or ODEs.

Comment: Yes, that was the point of my question. But yes, I should've stated "partial derivatives" and "ordinary derivatives" instead of PDEs and ODEs. However, the attached image is the context that they provided for their statement.

Comment: After reading more of the article, however, I am beginning to understand more of their notation. The authors claim that x is a function of y, and that y is a function of x. However, they do not write y(x), for instance, and they do not use the \partial symbol

Comment: Suppose that $y = f(x)$, and we provide $x = g(t)$ as a time series. Then you can write $y$ as a function of $t$ - it's $f(g(t))$. Then $\frac{dy}{dt} = f'(g(t))g'(t) = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$. No partial derivatives necessary - just overloaded notation.

Comment: I think that there's a problem if there are more variables than $2$. The thing is dead obvious for $2$ it's the chain rule as @preferred_anon says. But with more variables I just can't see it. In fact I don't believe it.

Comment: Thank you @preferred_anon (and ancient mathematician). I understand that this question isn't the greatest, but your responses help

Comment: @JustinBurzachiello Your question is fine! I share ancient mathematician's concern for multiple variables, but I don't know enough to answer it.